# Randomly select one of two possible texts

Tags: conditionals, random

Let's say I have two possible questions. I want only one to be on the generated PDF and I want this one to be randomly selected among the two potential candidates.

I thought this would be sufficient: (minimal code)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathifthenelse{\pgfmathrnd >= 0.5}{%
My first question.%
Potentially has more than one line.%
}{%
My second question%
Potentially has more than one line%
}

\end{document}
```

This seems logical to me: I generate a random number between 0 and 1, if it's greater than 0.5 I have a version, if it's lower than 0.5 I have another version, and since the random number is generated at each compile I have one of the two versions at each compile.

However, I get loads of errors. I figured that maybe I can't break the `{...}` of the `\ifthenelse` across lines, so for the sake of understanding I tried

```
\ifthenelse{\pgfmathrnd >= 0.5}{A}{B}
```

But still to no avail. I don't really understand if it should be `A` of `"A"` but the latter doesn't work either.

I also tried using `etoolbox` but without better results. (And as far as I understand it, the `toggle` has to be declared in the preamble, and in the best of words my two possible questions would be in a separate file that I would just `input` into the main file.)

---

**Background and why I want to do that**

I am doing a pen-and-paper experiment (think of it as a quiz or a survey). Questions have two possible answers. I want the order of the answers to be random to prevent order effects. Hence I want the question to be randomly

> This is the text of the question.
>
> (1) Answer alpha
>
> (2) Answer gamma
>
> Please answer (1) or (2)

or

> This is the text of the question.
>
> (1) Answer gamma
>
> (2) Answer alpha
>
> Please answer (1) or (2)

Say my experiment is a file `total.tex` and my questions are in a `questions.tex`. If I have 10 subjects, I will loop 10 times on the `\include{questions.tex}` to generate 10 decision sheets. I want those 10 decision sheets to be randomly different, hence my question.

Comment: One thing to consider: the random number generator is deterministic so to get different sequences you need to alter the initial seed with `\pgfmathsetseed{1234}` (1234 being the seed). Every time you compile you'll get the same random sequence; the individual sheets in the same document however will be different from each other.

Comment: To begin with, `\ifthenelse` doesn't know `>=` and doesn't accept decimal numbers.

Comment: Also, `\ifthenelse` is not a LaTeX command, are you including other packages such as `ifthen`?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I meant `\pgfmathifthenelse` not simply `\ifthenelse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick with PGF's random function

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}  % you do not need full tikz for this

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{
  \pgfmathrandom{2}  % store 1 or 2 in \pgfmathresult
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult>1%
    My first question.%
    Potentially has more than one line.%
  \else
    My second question%
    Potentially has more than one line%
  \fi
  \par
}

\end{document}
```

Keep in mind that every time you compile PGF will generate the same sequence of random numbers unless you specify a different seed using `\pgfmathsetseed`. To each different seed will correspond a different random sequence.

Comment: A late update, but I finally used this one. The other answer was finally too cumbersome to implement (I wanted to use `\emph` and I had to use `\noexpand` all the time)

Answer (score 4):

The macro `\ifthenelse` is not provided by default, but needs `\usepackage{ifthen}` or, better, `\usepackage{xifthen}`. However, its tests don't (easily) allow for decimal number comparisons.

You can do it with PGF features:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\first}{My first question.
Potentially has more than one line.}
\newcommand{\second}{My second question.
Potentially has more than one line.}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{rnd >= 0.5 ? "\first" : "\second"}\pgfmathresult

\pgfmathparse{rnd >= 0.5 ? "\first" : "\second"}\pgfmathresult

\pgfmathparse{rnd >= 0.5 ? "\first" : "\second"}\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

Of course you would define a macro for that, but this is left as an exercise.

[image]

Comment: the `x ? y : z` thing is just amazing. I had read again and again the manual but I didn't think of checking under 'Basic operators'. That's just so powerful!